# Guest User in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, security

When i Execute the Below Query it doesn't show me whether the guest account is enabled or disabled.

```
SELECT name, type_desc, is_disabled 
  FROM sys.server_principals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOU CAN TRY SOMETHING LIKE THIS:

SELECT U.UID, U.STATUS, U.NAME, U.SID, P.TYPE, P.TYPE_DESC, P.IS_DISABLED, P.NAME, P.PRINCIPAL_ID FROM SYSUSERS U LEFT OUTER JOIN SYS.SERVER_PRINCIPALS P ON U.[name] = P.[name]

Answer (score 0):

The guest *user* is actually *per database* so it would be listed in [sys.database_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx) (sys.server_principals is for server level security and *logins*).

The rights are contained in each databases [sys.database_permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188367.aspx). To connect to a database, you need CONNECT rights assigned:

```
CREATE USER foo FROM ...
GRANT CONNECT TO foo
```

So, what rows are there is sys.database_permissions for guest?